# how to get the last number of employeeid with plus one in powerapps

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps-canvas

I am working with power apps with SharePoint

I am trying to get the last maximum employee id from SharePoint and store it in powerapps

SharePoint

column name: EmpNo
column datatype: Number

[image]

**power apps canvas**

[image]

default - max length //but it gives an error

in SharePoint last employee id is **3** i want a store in **4** automatically in empno textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i'd do is get the heighest number from your data source to begin, then increment on it.

```
Max('SP DATASOURCE',EmpNo)+1
```

Something along those lines in the default should achieve what your after

Answer (score 0):

In your App's *OnStart*:

```
Set(LastID, Last(YourList).EmpNo);
Set(NextID, LastID+1);
```

Then, in the *EmpNo* control's *Default* property:

```
If (SharePointForm1.Mode = FormMode.New, 
    NextID,
    Parent.Default
)
```